# Junit Mocking a async thread call

Tags: java, asynchronous, junit, junit5

I am trying to unit test Class A, where Class A is as follows

```
Class A{
private final classB = new ClassB();


public Void test(ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent, Context context) {


        try {
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> doHandleRequest());
            thread2.start();
            thread2.join(3000);
            if (thread2.isAlive()) {
                thread2.interrupt();
                // sleep for 30 seconds to flush any logs or CFN metrics.
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }
    void doHandleRequest() {

        try {
            classB.sweep();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception in SweepThread while sweeping and deleting lambdas", ex);
        }
    }
}

Class B{
 public void sweep(){
// do something;
}
```

I want to unit test Class A scenario where thread2.isAlive() condition is true and it goes to that if block.

Comment: Why are you creating a `Thread` object? Use an `ExecutorService ` and catch the timeout on the `Future ` returned from `submit `.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change how you create `ClassB` object to allow mocking, it can not be done when objects get created every time.

You can do that like this

```
public class ClassA {
   private final ClassB b;

   // this will allow you to inject mock from outside, as it's final, can be initialized only via a constructor.

   public ClassA(ClassB b){
      this.b = b;
   }

  // your remaining code

}
```

And now, in your test case, you need to inject mocks.

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    ClassB classB = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
    ClassA classA = new ClassA(classB);

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  // this will initialize mocks

    //above can be skipped if you are using annotations for the same


    Mockito.stubVoid(classB)
      .toAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        return null;
      }).on().sweeps();

    parent.test(null, null);
}
```

To make sure, your thread is alive after `join`, you can add delay in mock method of `classB`.

As your method returns void, we need to use `stubVoid`, otherwise it will be like this.

```
Mockito.when(mock.method(/* args, if, any */)).thenAnswer(mock -> {
   Thread.sleep(delayInMilliseconds);
   return desiredValue;
})
```

Comment: Just wanted to answer more or less the same, this looks very good. You should give it a try.